# Execute Vim commands from shell

Tags: bash, shell

How to execute Vim commands from shell? For ex I want to see man pages of grep command in vim typing command from shell(bash,zsh) command something like:

`vim ':Man grep'`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From vim manpage:

```
  -c {command}
               {command} will be executed after the first file has been read.  {command} is  interpreted  as  an  Ex
               command.   If the {command} contains spaces it must be enclosed in double quotes (this depends on the
               shell that is used).  Example: Vim "+set si" main.c
               Note: You can use up to 10 "+" or "-c" commands.
```

From vim help:

```
To start using the ":Man" command before any manual page was loaded, source     
this script from your startup vimrc file:                                       

    runtime ftplugin/man.vim
```

Assuming you don't have man.vim sourced in vimrc, the following should work:

```
vim -c 'runtime ftplugin/man.vim' -c 'Man grep'
```

If you do have man.vim already sourcerd in vimrc, you can skip the explicit sourcing command argument to vim

And you'll probably want a shell script wrapper that will accept an argument so you'll be able to do something like

```
$ m ls
```

with content of m script being

```
#!/bin/sh

vim -c 'runtime ftplugin/man.vim' -c "Man $1"
```

Notice the usage of double quotes so **$1** gets understood properly by bash as the passed argument.

Of course you can always hit K on current word in vim to open the manpage for that word, but since you're explicitly telling that you want to do it from shell, I assume you know about this.

Comment: Thank You for great answer :) 1. This command `vim -c 'Man grep' works fine` under linux, but under Windows there is only empty file under vim. 2. Is it possible to create alias instead script file for this command :   `vim -c 'runtime ftplugin/man.vim' -c "Man $1"` so `m ls` would work as alias?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't say anything about Windows, because I'm not using it at all. For better visibility I suggest editing the question and requiring a solution that covers the Windows use case as well. I went for a script rather than an alias so I could pass the command name as argument. I'm not sure it's possible to do that with an alias.